# Bootstrap card footer not aligning to card bottom edge

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, card

In my MVC application, built on Bootstrap 4.6, I have this code in my view:

```
<div class="row no-gutters">

    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-2 d-flex">
                    
        <div class="card m-1">
            <div class="row no-gutters ">

                <div class="col-4 col-md-12">
                    <a href="@Url.Action("Advert", "Browse" , new { id=Model.Id })">
                        <img src="@imageUrl" class="img-fluid advert-card-img" alt="@Model.Title">
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div class="col-8 col-md-12">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <div class="text-truncate text-secondary">@Model.GroupName</div>
                        <div class="text-truncate">@Model.CategoryName</div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="advert-card-price text-primary">@Model.Price.ToMoneyString()<sup class="advert-card-currency">€</sup></div>
                        @Html.ActionLink(Model.Title, "Advert", "Browse", new { id = Model.Id }, new { @class = "advert-card-title" })
                    </div>

                    <div class="card-footer">
                        @if (Model.AccountSummary.IsBusiness)
                        {
                            <span class="badge badge-dark">Business</span>
                        }
                        <div class="text-secondary">
                            @Html.ActionLink(Model.AccountSummary.AccountName, "Profile", "Browse", new { id = Model.AccountSummary.AccountAliasId ?? Model.AccountSummary.AccountId, aid = Model.AccountSummary.AccountAliasId.HasValue }, new { @class = "text-truncate" })
                            <div class="text-truncate text-secondary">@Model.AccountSummary.CityName</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div

    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-2 d-flex">
                    
        <div class="card m-1">
            
            [...]
            
        </div

    </div>

</div>
```

I managed to get all the cards of the same height. I want to display the cards horizontal in mobile screen, hence the internal row/col structure. For some reason on non-mobile screen the card footer does not align to the bottom of the card, whereas without the internal row it works perfectly.

Here's a picture of how the cards are being displayed on desktop and mobile screens:

[image: Card footer not aligned properly on desktop]
[image: Not aligned properly on mobile either!]

JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/AMKC7/mo75bt24/)

How can I fix the issue?

Comment: You added a max-height (I am guessing) to the card as a whole and not individual parts of it. If you look closely, the card body has different amount of text in all cards, which is affecting it's height. So, wherever the card body has less text, your footer comes proper. Where it's not (like in 3rd card), it pushes the footer out of the card because of the fixed height of the entire card. So your best bet will be to have proper heights to each element of the card, and then manage your text.

Comment: @Siddharth thanks for your reply. Actually is the other way around, the 3rd card is the correct one. In the other cards the footer is expected to be at the bottom edge of the card. The gap highlighted in yellow is part of the card. There's no max-height, the cards are the same height as the external column (the card container) is d-flex.

Comment: Ah, I get it. I thought the other way around about the footer. Well, then given the cards are all proper height anyway, you need to make the card itself a column flex and then give the footer a fixed height. You'd also need to flex-fill the body. That way your head (automatically fixed at top) and footer (automatically fixed at bottom) make a sandwich with the body, and the body takes the entire space available.

Comment: @SiddharthBhansali those are set by Bootstrap already (I'm using 4.6). I think for some reason if the card contains a row/col something else is missing.

Comment: Could you make a jsfiddle with random data so we could debug it better?

Comment: Please tag your Bootstrap version, and please provide an HTML-only demo in a functioning snippet.

Comment: Also, it's inadvisable to override styles on core grid elements such as rows. Don't mess with the grid. Instead, style the grid _content_. Also, don't use inline styles. Use classes and a stylesheet, or at least an embedded style element.

Comment: JSFiddle added, and Bootstrap version tagged, thanks.